# HTTPS communicaton in TCL for windows

Tags: windows, http, ssl, https, tcl

I wish to download a file that resides on the server. I am setting a token and downloading the data.

```
package require http
package require twapi_crypto
http::register https 443 [list ::twapi::tls_socket]
set token [http::geturl "https://$ipaddress/filename"]
set status [http::status $token]
set data [http::data $token]
put $data
```

when I run this code, it gives the following error:

```
The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted
    while executing
"InitializeSecurityContext  $Credentials  $Handle  $Target  $Inattr  0  $Datarep  $inbuflist  0"
    (procedure "sspi_step" line 16)
    invoked from within
"sspi_step $SpiContext $data"
    (procedure "_negotiate2" line 19)
    invoked from within
"_negotiate2 $chan"
    (procedure "rethrow" line 2)
    invoked from within
"rethrow"
    invoked from within
"trap {
_negotiate2 $chan
} onerror {} {
variable channels
if {[info exists _channels($chan)]} {
dict set _chan..."
    (procedure "_negotiate line 3)
    invoked from within
"_negotiate $chan"
    (procedure "::twapi::tls::_so_write_andler" line12)
    invoked from within
"::twapi::tls::_so_write_handle rc0"
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. A similar code is implemented in Linux using tls and it works fine. All this comes in an exe and I am using starkit to make an exe.

Is there any other way to use https connection in windows apart from twapi?
I am not sure but I have used tls in windows, but the geturl ncode returns null value. Can this be because of SSL not being installed on windows machine?

PS: a similar error can be found in [TWAPI Bug #154](https://sourceforge.net/p/twapi/bugs/154/) but the resolution is not given.

Comment: Can you open the same link in Microsofts Internet Explorer without warning? If not you might need to install the proper CA certificates as trusted.

Comment: Looks like it is the same fundamental issue as https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/568 (i.e., same call into the core of Windows and same failure code). Fix is to force Windows to trust the certificate of the host that you're trying to connect to (or the relevant parent CA) and otherwise fix the security config. TWAPI should work once Internet Explorer and/or Edge are able to talk to the host too.

Comment: @schlenk No. I cannot open the link without the warning. Are you saying when building a TLS request, I should pass the certificate?

Comment: @DonalFellows I have added the certificate in the windows trust certificate. It gives the same error with a different warning
"The target principal name is incorrect"

Comment: The solution was to install the certificate in the IE as well as in windows trusted CA store.